# On which site can I ask medicine questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about medicine? For example, about the operating principles of a ventilator (CPAP mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Health Stack Exchange](https://health.stackexchange.com/). According to their [help center](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), they welcome questions about

> - Medications and other interventions that are used to treat diseases

---

Note that

> Health Stack Exchange is for [educational purposes only](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer).

Comment: Hello @Glorfindel thank you for your answer. If you know also other forums, tell them to me please.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi you're welcome. We generally don't recommend sites outside the network, unless your question is not suitable for Stack Exchange.